# Cookie is only set on the initial page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I am setting a cookie in JavaScript (with an ASP.NET app). I can refresh the page and I can verify that the cookie is set with `document.cookie`. Now if I go to any other page, the cookie is not set, but it should be. I am not setting a path, so I don't see any reason why it isn't showing up. I've tried Chrome, FF, and IE and nothing.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Here's the code I used to set the cookie. I also tried jquery.cookie

```
function Set_Cookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
    // set time, it's in milliseconds
    var today = new Date();
    today.setTime(today.getTime());

    /*
    if the expires variable is set, make the correct
    expires time, the current script below will set
    it for x number of days, to make it for hours,
    delete * 24, for minutes, delete * 60 * 24
    */
    if (expires) {
        expires = expires * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    }
    var expires_date = new Date(today.getTime() + (expires));

    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
        ((expires) ? ";expires=" + expires_date.toGMTString() : "") +
        ((path) ? ";path=" + path : "") +
        ((domain) ? ";domain=" + domain : "") +
        ((secure) ? ";secure" : "");
}

Set_Cookie('cookie1', 'value1', 14);
$.cookie('cookie2', 'value2');
```

Comment: How exactly are you setting cookie? Could you provide a piece of code?

Comment: You send the cookie to the server and then pass it back in the response and it's not there, or what is the scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the path to '/'. I resisted doing that cause it sounded dumb. It should be that by default, right? I guess not.